# Is the MC produced by HMC reversible?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo, mcmc-acceptance-rate

I know that the deterministic dynamics in Hamiltonian Monte Carlo/Hybrid Monte Carlo are reversible and the numerical integrators one uses to approximate them are reversible too. But HMC consists of 2 steps:

1. Sample velocity
2. Run Hamiltonian Dynamics with accept/reject

From the reversibility of the integrator and the form of the accept/reject ratio I guess one can show that the step 2 is reversible. But is the full algorithm with step 1 and step 2 reversible with respect to the measure one wants to sample?